# How to create multiple log files in log4j2 using property file?

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using .property file to create log file in specific path but i am creating single file using that. Following is my code of property file:

```
    status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filepath= /ap
property.filename =${filepath}/ai.log
property.filename1 =${filepath}/file1.log
property.filename2 =${filepath}/file2.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.file.type = RollingFile
appender.file.name = RootFile1
appender.file.fileName = ${filename}
appender.file.filePattern = ${filepath}/%d{yyyyMMdd}/cpl.mw.%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.log.gz
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
#appender.file.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.file.policies.type = Policies
appender.file.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.file.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.file.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.file.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.file.policies.size.size=50MB
appender.file.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.file.strategy.max = 20

appender.rolling1.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling1.name = RollingFile1
appender.rolling1.fileName = ${filename1}
appender.rolling1.filePattern = ${filepath}/%d{yyyyMMdd}/cpl.mw.%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.log.gz
appender.rolling1.layout.type = PatternLayout
#appender.rolling1.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling1.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling1.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling1.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling1.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling1.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling1.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling1.policies.size.size=50MB
appender.rolling1.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling1.strategy.max = 20



appender.rolling2.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling2.name = RollingFile2
appender.rolling2.fileName = ${filename2}
appender.rolling2.filePattern = ${filepath}/%d{yyyyMMdd}/cpl.mw.%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.log.gz
appender.rolling2.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling2.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling2.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling2.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling2.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling2.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling2.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling2.policies.size.size=50MB
appender.rolling2.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling2.strategy.max = 20

loggers
logger.name=file1
logger.level = debug
logger.additivity = true
logger.appenderRefs = rolling1,stdout
logger.appenderRefs.level = debug
logger.appenderRef.rolling1.ref = RollingFile1
logger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

logger.name=file2
logger.level = debug
logger.additivity = true
logger.appenderRefs = rolling2
logger.appenderRefs.level = debug
logger.appenderRef.rolling2.ref = RollingFile2
```

above code is of my xyz.properties file i want to create multiple logs using this configuration file.My property configuration file create multiple file but not put different different logs in log files.I call this from JAVA using below code:

```
private static final Logger logCommon = LogManager.getLogger("file1");
private static final Logger logAnalytics = LogManager.getLogger("file2");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    logCommon.info ("file1 Need it save into commons.log file");
    logAnalytics.info ("file2 Only save into analytics.log file");

}
```

`2018-01-22 12:52:23 INFO  file2:301 - file2 Only save into analytics.log file` log put in both log files.

I refer below links:

[Log4j2: Dynamic creation of log files for multiple logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052070/log4j2-dynamic-creation-of-log-files-for-multiple-logs)

[Wildcard pattern for RoutingAppender of Log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279656/wildcard-pattern-for-routingappender-of-log4j2)

[How to write different logs in different files with log4j2 (MDC in xml)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827923/how-to-write-different-logs-in-different-files-with-log4j2-mdc-in-xml)

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html

i refer below links but not get any solution:

[How to implement multi file appender in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949416/how-to-implement-multi-file-appender-in-log4j2)

[How to avoid multiple log files in slf4j logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003905/how-to-avoid-multiple-log-files-in-slf4j-logging)

[log4j2 - generate application specific log files in weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053283/log4j2-generate-application-specific-log-files-in-weblogic)

[How to create multiple log files of different content with log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285254/how-to-create-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076316/using-properties-in-log4j2-yaml)

[log4j2 KeyValuePair for .properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649383/log4j2-keyvaluepair-for-properties-file)

[How to Create a Custom Appender in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j2)

[Configuring async loggers in log4j2.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600724/configuring-async-loggers-in-log4j2-properties)

[How to create custom RewritePolicy in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247323/how-to-create-custom-rewritepolicy-in-log4j2)

[How to set the log level on a class in log4j2 properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995946/how-to-set-the-log-level-on-a-class-in-log4j2-properties)

[Increasing file indexing on OnStartupTriggeringPolicy in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406603/increasing-file-indexing-on-onstartuptriggeringpolicy-in-log4j2)

[how to configure log file path to current working target directory in log4j2 xml format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869975/how-to-configure-log-file-path-to-current-working-target-directory-in-log4j2-xml)

[How to configure RestTemplate debug logging in log4j2 xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215119/how-to-configure-resttemplate-debug-logging-in-log4j2-xml)

[Creating multiple log files in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137850/creating-multiple-log-files-in-iphone-app)

[Log4j2 using multiple appender and logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499188/log4j2-using-multiple-appender-and-logger)

[How to create multiple log file programatically in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336225/how-to-create-multiple-log-file-programatically-in-log4j2)

[How to create multiple log file programatically in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336225/how-to-create-multiple-log-file-programatically-in-log4j2)

[How to specify log file in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508300/how-to-specify-log-file-in-log4j2)

[Log separate log levels to separate files in log4j2 properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287020/log-separate-log-levels-to-separate-files-in-log4j2-properties-file)

[Unable to create multiple log files based on the ThreadContext map values using routing appender in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910176/unable-to-create-multiple-log-files-based-on-the-threadcontext-map-values-using)

[How to create Custom Rolling File appender in log4j2 - customized file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669056/how-to-create-custom-rolling-file-appender-in-log4j2-customized-file-name)

[Different log files for multiple threads using log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976211/different-log-files-for-multiple-threads-using-log4j2)

[Log4j2 YAML generate multiple log files issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717645/log4j2-yaml-generate-multiple-log-files-issue)

[How to create multiple log files using log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941144/how-to-create-multiple-log-files-using-log4j)

[Log4j2 - Overriding log file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332241/log4j2-overriding-log-file-programmatically)

[How to create a rolling file appender plugin in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412710/how-to-create-a-rolling-file-appender-plugin-in-log4j2)

Comment: Hey, try this link [Logger link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652032/how-can-i-create-2-separate-log-files-with-one-log4j-config-file)

Comment: @CowboyFarnz  i want property file of log4j2 not log4j

Comment: I am new in log4j2 configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please set `additivity=false` for both named loggers.

Also, add a root logger configuration to tell Log4j2 where to send the logging calls other than the “file1” and “file2” loggers:

```
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Also, give your named loggers a unique prefix:

```
logger.aaa.name = file1
logger.aaa.additivity = false
logger.aaa.level = debug
logger.aaa.appenderRef.rrr.ref = RollingFile1

logger.bbb.name = file2
logger.bbb.additivity = false
logger.bbb.level = debug
logger.bbb.appenderRef.sss.ref = RollingFile2
```

Comment: both file store same log:

Comment: What do you see?

Comment: 2018-01-29 15:40:42 INFO  Logbook:190 - file2 Only save into analytics.log file

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Use below configuration and call addLogger() whenever you want to use with fully qualified path

```
public static void addLogger(String parentPath) throws SecurityException, IOException {
        try {
            InputStream in = ConfiguratorHelper.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/mylogging.properties"); 
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(in);
        } catch (SecurityException | IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
        logger.addHandler(new MyHandler());
        try {
            //FileHandler file name with max size and number of log files limit
            Handler fileHandler = new FileHandler(path, 1000000, 10);
            fileHandler.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());
            fileHandler.setFilter(new MyFilter());
            logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
            logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "Config data");
        } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord log) {
        //don't log CONFIG logs in file
        if(log.getLevel() == Level.CONFIG) return false;
        return true;
    }

}


public class MyFormatter extends Formatter {

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        return record.getThreadID()+"::"+record.getSourceClassName()+"::"
                +record.getSourceMethodName()+"::"
                +new Date(record.getMillis())+"::"
                +record.getMessage()+"\n";
    }

}

public class MyHandler extends StreamHandler {

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        //add own logic to publish
        super.publish(record);
    }


    @Override
    public void flush() {
        super.flush();
    }


    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
        super.close();
    }

}
```